# How to get rid of dbo. from primary , foreign keys and index names created through code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database created through code first approach and all the pk, fk and index names are created with `dbo.`, for example `PK_dbo.VendorID` and I would like them to be `PK_VendorID` same with fk's and index names.

I have followed these approaches:

First approach:
Visit [How can I stop Entity Framework 5 migrations adding dbo. into key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053627/how-can-i-stop-entity-framework-5-migrations-adding-dbo-into-key-names)

When I run the `update-database` command it asks me to disable the automatic migration and also enable the data loss  but my projects will do automatic migrations ...

Second approach:
Visit [How to Specify Primary Key Name in EF-Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607512/how-to-specify-primary-key-name-in-ef-code-first)

I am able to achieve by using `sp_rename`, but I have many changes to pk, fk and index names ..

Please let me know how I can strip off the `dbo.` prefix from pk, fk and index names. I am beginner in coding.

```
public class MigrationSqlGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(DropIndexOperation dropIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        dropIndexOperation.Table = StripDbo(dropIndexOperation.Table);

        base.Generate(dropIndexOperation, writer);
    }

    //protected override void Generate(AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    //{
    //    addForeignKeyOperation.Name = this.StripDbo(addForeignKeyOperation.Name, addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable);
    //    addForeignKeyOperation.Name = this.StripDbo(addForeignKeyOperation.Name, addForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable);
    //    base.Generate(addForeignKeyOperation, writer);
    //}

    //protected override void Generate(AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    //{
    //    addPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = StripDbo(addPrimaryKeyOperation.Name, addPrimaryKeyOperation.Table);
    //    base.Generate(addPrimaryKeyOperation, writer);
    //}

    //protected override void Generate(DropForeignKeyOperation dropForeignKeyOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    //{
    //    dropForeignKeyOperation.Name = this.StripDbo(dropForeignKeyOperation.Name, dropForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable);
    //    dropForeignKeyOperation.Name = this.StripDbo(dropForeignKeyOperation.Name, dropForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable);
    //    base.Generate(dropForeignKeyOperation, writer);
    //}

    //protected override void Generate(DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    //{
    //    dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = StripDbo(dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Name, dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Table);
    //    base.Generate(dropPrimaryKeyOperation, writer);
    //}

    //private string StripDbo(string objectName, string tableName)
    //{
    //    if (tableName.StartsWith("dbo."))
    //    {
    //        return objectName.Replace(tableName, tableName.Substring(4));
    //    }

    //    return objectName;
    //}

    // TODO: Override other Generate overloads that involve table names

    private string StripDbo(string table)
    {
        if (table.StartsWith("dbo."))
        {
            return table.Substring(4);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

- FromName: `PK_dbo.VendorID`
- ToName: `PK_VendorID`

Comment: public partial class Update_FKPK_Names : DbMigration
    {

        public override void Up()
        {

            //var keyAttributes = AddToDictionaryConvention.AttributesConventions();

            var fromName = "PK_dbo.VendorID";
            var toName = "PK_VendorID";

            foreach (var attribute in keyAttributes)
            {
                Sql($"exec sp_rename @objname=N'[dbo].[{fromName}]', @newname=N'{toName}'");
            }
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should clarify what your comment means. In case it's the answer to your own question, post it as an answer (you can) so that others can benefit.

Comment: i am looking for answer ..its not the answer @s.m