# EF migration for changing data type of columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Model in my project as below:

```
public class Model 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long FromNo { get; set; }
    public long ToNo { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public long TicketNo { get; set; }
}
```

The migration is as below

```
public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "FromNo", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "ToNo", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "TicketNo", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
}
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "FromNo", c => c.String());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "ToNo", c => c.String());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "TicketNo", c => c.String());
}
```

when I use Update-Database the error below is raised:

> The object 'DF__Receiv__FromN__25869641' is dependent on column
>   'FromNo'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN FromNo failed because one or more
>   objects access this column.

This tables has no foreign key or what else so what is the problem?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have a default constraint on your column. You need to first drop the constraint, then alter your column.

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Received DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Receiv_FromN__25869641");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "FromNo", c => c.String());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "ToNo", c => c.String());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "TicketNo", c => c.String());
}
```

You will probably have to drop the default constraints on your other columns as well.

I've just seen Andrey's comment (I know - very late) and he is correct. So a more robust approach would be to use something like:

```
 DECLARE @con nvarchar(128)
 SELECT @con = name
 FROM sys.default_constraints
 WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('dbo.Received')
 AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'FromNo';
 IF @con IS NOT NULL
     EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Received] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @con)
```

I know this probably doesn't help the OP but hopefully it helps anyone else that comes across this issue.

Comment: The constraint name is autogenerated by SQL Server. While this code will work in development environment - it won't in the production because in the different database the constraint name will be different

Comment: Very nice approach. Specially the second one. Works perfectly.

Comment: @Bigfellahull Sorry to be a dim wit - where would you place the second version of your answer?

Comment: @DaveGordon: You would put it in the call to the `Sql()` method, like this:

   `Sql(@"DECLARE @con nvarchar(128)
 SELECT @con = name
 FROM sys.default_constraints
 WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('dbo.Received')
 AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'FromNo';
 IF @con IS NOT NULL
     EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Received] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @con)");`

Comment: the query worked well in removing the DF but In my case altering a DateTime to TimeSpan field, this caused a new error - The object 'DF_dbo.Entity_Column' is dependent on column 'Column'. Is there a query to also remove this?

Comment: @ScottDorman - What are the consequences of dropping the constraints? After running my migration I see that EF did not add new constraints to replace the old ones. How is the effect of these constraints being removed?

Comment: It is much easier to rename old column, create the a new one, then Sql("UPDATE ... ColName = RenamedOldColName ...."), and then DropColumn("oldrenamedCol")

Comment: Even though AlterColumn says if no schema is specified dbo is assumed, I had not specified dbo and it failed.

Answer (score 43):

```
static internal class MigrationExtensions
{
    public static void DeleteDefaultConstraint(this IDbMigration migration, string tableName, string colName, bool suppressTransaction = false)
    {
        var sql = new SqlOperation(
            string.Format(@"DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)
                            SET @SQL='ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT ['+(SELECT name
                            FROM sys.default_constraints
                            WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('{0}')
                            AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = '{1}')+']';
                            PRINT @SQL;
                            EXEC(@SQL);", tableName, colName)
            )
        {
            SuppressTransaction = suppressTransaction
        };
        migration.AddOperation(sql);
    }
}

public override void Up()
{
    this.DeleteDefaultConstraint("dbo.Received", "FromNo");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "FromNo", c => c.String());
    this.DeleteDefaultConstraint("dbo.Received", "ToNo");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "ToNo", c => c.String());
    this.DeleteDefaultConstraint("dbo.Received", "TicketNo");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Received", "TicketNo", c => c.String());
}
```

Comment: This works perfect, better than accepted answer, because its dynamic and not hardcoded.

Comment: I tried this and got the error: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "XXXX2.DAL.Migrations.ChangeProcessedToByte.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "XXXX2.DAL" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: @Kleky I had this problem and solved it by putting the MigrationExtensions class in a different file to the migration (in my case a MigrationExtensions.cs within the Migrations folder).

Comment: This solution misses the `Down()` method.

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to solve the problem for ever.

You can implement a custom sql generator class derived from SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator from System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

namespace System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql{
    internal class FixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator {
        protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation){
            ColumnModel column = alterColumnOperation.Column;
            var sql = String.Format(@"DECLARE @ConstraintName varchar(1000);
            DECLARE @sql varchar(1000);
            SELECT @ConstraintName = name   FROM sys.default_constraints
                WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('{0}')
                AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = '{1}';
            IF(@ConstraintName is NOT Null)
                BEGIN
                set @sql='ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName+ ']';
            exec(@sql);
            END", alterColumnOperation.Table, column.Name);
                this.Statement(sql);
            base.Generate(alterColumnOperation);
            return;
        }
        protected override void Generate(DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation){
            var sql = String.Format(@"DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)
                SET @SQL='ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT [' + (SELECT name
                    FROM sys.default_constraints
                    WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('{0}')
                    AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = '{1}') + ']';
            PRINT @SQL;
                EXEC(@SQL); ", dropColumnOperation.Table, dropColumnOperation.Name);

                    this.Statement(sql);
            base.Generate(dropColumnOperation);
        }
    }
}
```

and Set this configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new FixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator ());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for changing an existing column to 'not null' that already has a foreign key constraint.
The column's name is "FKColumnName" in table "SubTable" and it is referencing the "Id" column in table "MainTable".

**Up script:**

After the column is made 'not nullable' the index and the foreign key first dropped and then re-created.

**Down script:**

Here the steps are identical except that the column is made nullable again.

```
public partial class NameOfMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", "dbo.MainTable");
        DropIndex("dbo.SubTable", new[] { "FKColumnName" });

        AlterColumn("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

        CreateIndex("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", "dbo.MainTable", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", "dbo.MainTable");
        DropIndex("dbo.SubTable", new[] { "FKColumnName" });

        AlterColumn("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", c => c.Int(nullable: true));

        CreateIndex("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.SubTable", "FKColumnName", "dbo.MainTable", "Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me except I changed the `new[] { "FKColumnName" }` to `"IX_ColumnName"` for the index since that was the name of it in my database.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with a default value of zero constraint on an integer column.

In my case I solved it by switching from Entity Framework 6.1.x to EF 6.2.0.

There's a known bug in EF prior to 6.2 that means that EF sometimes doesn't deal with these types of constraints automatically when altering columns.  That bug is described on the [official EF github repo here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/54), Bricelam describes the issue as:

> When adding NOT NULL columns, we synthesize a default value for any
>   existing rows. It looks like our logic to drop default constraints
>   before ALTER COLUMN doesn't take this into account.

The commit for the fix for that issue [can be found here](https://github.com/bricelam/EntityFramework6/commit/15de49003c43365307408b408dc57252847f9803).

Answer (score -16):

If you're using EF:

- Delete the migration folder and the database
- `enable-migrations`
- `add-migration initial`
- `update-database`

Although, this solution would remove all current items in the database.  If this is not your intention, I would suggest one of the other answers.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Unless your project is brand new. Don't listen to this person.

Comment: I cant imagine why anyone would every want to do this this way