# Foreign Key Error with Code-First Migration: Can't drop Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I’ve got a problem with Entity Framework and doing a Migration (database-update) and Foreign Key Annotations.
The error message that I get is after: `update-database –verbose`

```
Applying automatic migration: 201604060846578_AutomaticMigration.
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_OutreachSet_TargetContact' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[DiagnosticsSets]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_OutreachSet_TargetContact] ON [dbo].[DiagnosticsSets]
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_OutreachSet_TargetContact' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MotivationSets]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_OutreachSet_TargetContact] ON [dbo].[MotivationSets]
DECLARE @var0 nvarchar(128)
SELECT @var0 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.MotivationSets')
AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'TargetContact';
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL
    EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MotivationSets] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + ']')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MotivationSets] DROP COLUMN [TargetContact]
```

[...]

```
The object 'PK_dbo.MotivationSets' is dependent on column 'TargetContact'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN TargetContact failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I’d just like to have a 0:0…1 Relationship. That's it.

I’d tried to do it just like in this example [EF Code-First One-to-one relationship: Multiplicity is not valid in Role * in relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389707/ef-code-first-one-to-one-relationship-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role-in-re)

```
 public class OutreachSet
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Target Contact")]
        public string TargetContact { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Next Outreach Step")]
        public string NextOutreachStep { get; set; }

        public virtual MotivationSet MotivationSet { get; set; }
}

 public class MotivationSet
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("OutreachSet")]
        public string TargetContact { get; set; }

        public string PowerMastery { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public virtual OutreachSet OutreachSet { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it myself.
I just did this: [How to re-create database for Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304058/how-to-re-create-database-for-entity-framework)

If anyone still could tell me why this happend I'd be happy

Thank you!

Comment: You probably changed your model in a way migrations could not handle by default - changing the identity status, FK renames, are examples. By deleting everything and starting over you avoid the renames and everything is created from scratch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894906/ef-migration-for-changing-data-type-of-columns

Comment: What if you can't start from scratch?