# How do I get entity framework to add SQL constraints during a DB migration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, constraints, entity-framework-migrations

First off I am sorry this question is so long. I really dontknow what information is relevant so I gave as much as possible.

I have an asp.net (.net framework 4.5.2) MVC5 application with an Entity Framework 6 (Code-First) I am trying to do a relatively simple DB migration wherein I change a column (called SchedulkedWeeklyHours) from an int to a decimal(decimal being the name of the datatype in C#). I did the add-migration command no problem but when I tried the update-database command I got this error:

```
The object 'DF__CompanyUs__Schde__43A1090D' is dependent on column 
'SchdeduledWeeklyHours'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SchdeduledWeeklyHours failed because one or more 
objects access this column.
```

This is the DB migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.CompanyUsers", "SchdeduledWeeklyHours", c => 
        c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.CompanyUsers", "SchdeduledWeeklyHours", c => 
        c.Int(nullable: false));
    }
```

that changed this field in the CompanyUser model from this:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Scheduled Weekly Hours")]
    [Range(0, (7*24+1))]
    public int SchdeduledWeeklyHours { get; set; } = 40;
```

to this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Scheduled Weekly Hours")]
[Range(0.0, (7.0*24.0+1.0))]
public decimal SchdeduledWeeklyHours { get; set; } = 40.00M;
```

In order to get the update-database command to work I had to manually delete the constraint, which I did and then the command worked fine. However, I was expecting that since I had the same nullable: false key-value pair in both alter column statements that a new not nullable constraint would be added to that table in SQL but when I check the constraints using alt-F1 I got the following before the migration:

[This is the DB constrants before the migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CaMl.png)

[The is the DB constraints after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M7Qm.png)

My question is why is a new not nullable constraint not being generated even though when I tested it I still cannot leave that field null (I tried) and it still has the correct default value? The reason I am asking is that a more senior developer does not think it is a good idea to just go into the staging DB  and delete the constraint like I did on my local version because it might make reverting impossible. How do I deal with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894906/ef-migration-for-changing-data-type-of-columns). If that other question helps, let me know and we can link this thread to that one

Comment: @RemedialBear I have seen that question and not really because it doesnt dela with why EF isnt adding a new constraint afterwards. Most of the answers there just deal with dropping the original constraint and never adding a new one back on

Comment: When adding the new column, presumably you would add the desired constraints as well just like how the original constraints were created, because in effect you're adding an entirely new column not modifying the existing one. However, I agree that I have no answer as to _why_ entity framework has so much trouble with these kinds of things. I'm fortunate in that when I have encountered similar issues we weren't really concerned with reverting, but I feel your pain