# Entity framework code first migration not always working well

Tags: entity-framework, migration, code-first

I have created a migration for my recent changes to my model that resulted in the following script,

```
        DropIndex("dbo.InboundActions", new[] { "ReferredFrom_Id1" });
        DropIndex("dbo.InboundCopyActionLogs", new[] { "InboundReferToEmployee_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.InboundCopyActions", new[] { "ReferredFrom_Id1" });
        DropColumn("dbo.InboundActions", "ReferredFrom_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.InboundCopyActions", "ReferredFrom_Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.InboundCopyActionLogs", name: "InboundReferToDivision_Id", newName: "InboundRefer_Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.InboundCopyActions", name: "ReferredFrom_Id1", newName: "ReferredFrom_Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.InboundCopyActionLogs", name: "InboundReferToEmployee_Id", newName: "InboundRefer_Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.InboundActions", name: "ReferredFrom_Id1", newName: "ReferredFrom_Id");
        RenameIndex(table: "dbo.InboundCopyActionLogs", name: "IX_InboundReferToDivision_Id", newName: "IX_InboundRefer_Id");
```

Now when I try to update the database I get the following errors,

> The index 'IX_ReferredFrom_Id' is dependent on column 'ReferredFrom_Id'.
>   The object 'FK_dbo.InboundActions_dbo.Divisions_ReferredFrom_Id' is dependent on column 'ReferredFrom_Id'.
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ReferredFrom_Id failed because one or more objects access this column.

This is not the first time I find this kind of errors with migrations, which forces to me drop all migrations and database and start with brand new migrations which of course isn't practical, is there a problem with EF or me?!

Comment: You are running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894906/ef-migration-for-changing-data-type-of-columns). If you are in a stage of development where you are frequently renaming columns and drastically changing the models you might consider holding off on migrations and using the database initializers that drop and recreate your database. Use seeding to keep your essential data.

Comment: But this model change I have just did might very easily happen after deployment, in this case I will be in great trouble since I will not be able to drop and create database, any solutions?

Comment: Yes, as the link mentions you are running into this because there are constraints that must be dropped before the rename of the FK can take place. This is a problem with EF, so you will need to code your own `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ..." ahead of the rename(s).

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear. It is another Microsoft flaw! Just wanted to make sure I am not doing anything wrong.